# Datadog shows a limited number of transaction logs

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have been trying group some logs in transactions between 2 services, it works great but when I increase the duration of logs it always caps at 30 transactions no matter the amount of logs, looks like there is a limitation that I'm not aware of. (btw it always shows 30 first transactions found)

I expect to see more then 30 transaction logs in my explorer, example when I lower the time to last 1hr logs, I see all of them (usually 7 - 10 transactions).